# Fun with uninitialized variables and compiler (GCC)

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, undefined-behavior, initialization

The section §3.9.1/6 from the C++ Standard says,

> Values of type bool are either `true` or `false`.

Now consider this code,

```
void f(bool b)
{
    switch(b) //since b is bool, it's value can be either true or false!
    {
        case true: cout << "possible value - true";  break;
        case false: cout << "possible value - false"; break;
        default: cout << "impossible value";
    }
}
int main()
{
    bool b; //note : b is uninitialized
    f(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile  `F:\workplace>g++ test.cpp -pedantic`

Run. Output :

> impossible value

Unexpected output? Well, not really, as the Standard reads in the footnote of §3.9.1/6 that:

> Using a bool value in ways described
>   by this International Standard as
>   **“undefined,”** such as **by examining the value of an
>   uninitialized** automatic object,
>   might cause it to **behave as if it is
>   neither true nor false**.

So no matter how many times I compile and run this program, I get the same output : `impossible value`. However, if I change it a bit - removing the function `f()` from the picture, and write the `switch` block in `main()` itself:

```
int main()
{
    bool b; //note : b is uninitialized
    switch(b) //since b is bool, it's value can be either true or false!
    {
        case true: cout << "possible value - true";  break;
        case false: cout << "possible value - false"; break;
        default: cout << "impossible value";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then I compile and run this program, I don't get `impossible value` as output; no matter how many times I repeat this, I never get `impossible value`.

I'm just curious to know why this sudden change in the behavior of uninitialized bool?

Well, from the language perspective it's clear : the behavior is undefined.I understand that. I also understand the compiler is free to do anything. From the compiler perspective, however, this seems very interesting to me. What could the *compiler* (i.e GCC) possibly do in each case and why?

I'm using : `g++ (GCC) 4.5.0 - MinGW, on Windows 7 Basic, 64-bit OS`.

Comment: I cannot replicate your results with g++-4.4.5 amd64. But if you want to answer yourself these kind of question, why don't you just examine the compiler assembly output ?

Comment: Do you get the same results if you turn on code optimisation?

Comment: So your question is why "Undefined Behavior" is different when exposed in different situations? For somebody that knows it is undefined I can't think of a more ridiculous questions! and can only see it as a question designed to try and generate points. -500

Comment: @Martin: It seems you didn't read my question : *What could the compiler (i.e GCC) possibly do in each case and why?*. The question is more about the compiler than the language. The compiler must be doing something in each case, right?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I'm just curious to know why this sudden change in the behavior of uninitialized bool?

Disassemble the code and see what the compiler’s doing.

My guess: since the value is now only used locally, the compiler optimizes it away completely. Since the behaviour is undefined anyway, the compiler can safely just assume any value, e.g. `false`. This is a pretty obvious optimization since the value of `b` is constant as far as the compiler is concerned, and the whole logic of the `switch` is redundant. So why put it in the executable?

(The important point here is really that `b` is only ever used locally in the second code, and that in turn will trigger more optimizations even in unoptimized code. The first code has to be inlined before the compiler can do any such optimizations, or the code paths have to be traced which isn’t trivial).

Answer (score 1):

Just today I came across a version of this bug.  I offer my experience here in case it's enlightening to anyone else.

I had some code which boiled down to

```
if(!(a == b && c.d())) { do_something(); }
```

The bug I was chasing was that `do_something()` was happening, wrongly.  Yet `a` was definitely equal to `b` and `c.d()` was, it seemed, returning true.

As I was tracking this down, I temporarily added these test printouts:

```
if(  a == b && c.d() ) printf("yes\n"; else printf("no\n");
if(!(a == b && c.d())) printf("noo\n"; else printf("yess\n");
```

To my surprise this printed `yes` and `noo`, which confirmed both why `do_something` was happening, and that something very strange was going on.

It turned out that method `d()` was something like

```
bool whatever::d() {
    return _successful;
}
```

But `_successful` was uninitialized.  When I printed out its value, it was 236, which is why earlier I had said "`c.d()` was, it seemed, returning true."

I didn't inspect the assembly code, but I'm guessing that under some circumstances, gcc was testing whether it was nonzero or not, but under others, it was just testing the low-order bit.

Properly initializing `_successful` made the bug go away.  (It had been uninitialized for *ten years*, since an earlier programmer first wrote method `d()`.  Yet the bug hadn't manifested until a few months ago.  This is why, sometimes, Software Is Hard.)

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, which was about what the compiler does and why it behaves differently in different cases.

Comment: @aschepler "I'm guessing that under some circumstances, gcc was testing whether it was nonzero or not, but under others, it was just testing the low-order bit."  That's the main part of the answer, on top of the obvious uncertainty as to which random uninitialized value you'll get.

Comment: @aschepler: Even if it's not an answer, it's interesting to know that such bugs can stay in your code for a decade!! ... and from that perspective, it is a valuable post for this topic. Also, there is no answer other than that it is UB, which even this answer seems to say.