# Don't understand the output of this C program

Tags: c

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int value[10];
    int index;

    value[0] = 197;
    value[2] = -100;
    value[5] = 350;
    value[3] = value[0] + value[5];
    value[9] = value[5] / 10;
    --value[2];

    for(index = 0; index < 10; ++index)
        printf("value[%i] = %i\n", index, value[index]);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output when compile:

```
value[0] = 197
value[1] = 0
value[2] = -101
value[3] = 547
value[4] = 0
value[5] = 350
value[6] = 0
value[7] = 0
value[8] = 1784505816
value[9] = 35
```

I don't understand why value[8] returns 1784505816? 
Isn't value[8] supposed be = value[6] = value[7] = 0? By the way, I compile the code via gcc under Mac OS X Lion.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`value[8]` was never initialized, therefore its contents are undefined and can be anything.

Same applies to `value[1]`, `value[4]`, `value[6]`, and `value[7]`. But they just happened to be zero.

Comment: But if you used `int value[10] = {};`, then they would be zero-initialised.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: You mean `{0}`. This is a C question.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: +1 Wow, good call. I see that `{}` is a gcc extension (and when compiling with `-pedantic`, you get a "warning: ISO C forbids empty initializer braces" message). (It's too late for me to edit my comment now, alas.)

Comment: `its contents are undefined`? The Standard uses the term *indeterminate*,  not *undefined*. See this : [Fun with uninitialized variables and compiler (GCC)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879045/fun-with-uninitialized-variables-and-compiler-gcc)

Answer (score 6):

Objects with automatic storage duration declared without an initializer have indeterminate values until they are assigned to. Technically, it causes *undefined behavior* to use the value (e.g. printing int) of an object which has an indeterminate value.

If you want the array to be initialized to zero you need to provide an initializer. E.g.

```
int value[10] = {0};
```